# Remove an item in Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm using AngularFire but if the solution is in the way of pure JavaScript it will be welcome.

I have a Firebase Collection similar to this:

```
productExample: {
    name: 'Motorbike',
    category: 'Cross',
    images: {
        0: 'image1.jpg',
        1: 'image2.jpg',
        2: 'image3.jpg'
    } 
}
```

I want to remove the image1.jpg. ¿How can I do it? I've tried so many things but I have not got the solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you've tried something, show the [minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Because without that, we have no idea what direction you're trying. E.g. `firebase.database().ref("productExample/images/0").remove()` will work, but is likely not what you want.

Comment: Have you tried binding your Firebase database to a scope variable and then trying to remove the element you want? Show us what you have tried so far, so that we could be of help